# printing a pattern of '*'

Tags: c++, cout

As an assignment, I used for-loop like the following

```
for(int i=0; i<size(); i++) { //code}
```

The answer came out to be identical except for the increment part,

```
++i
```

Is there any advantage to use i++ over ++i for any reasons?

Please help.

EDIT : looking back and editing my old questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Comment: you want to know the difference between *pre-increment* and *post-increment*, and *string literals* and *character literals*.

Comment: Oh is that the reason why I got instant -3?

Comment: @Minjae possibly, it could also be the content in your question or lack of research. I didn't downvote you though.

Comment: Code indentation is not important for the compiler, but it is for humans reading your code. The second example you show might easily be misread because of the lack of indentation. Please try to learn to indent your code in some way.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Thanks though :) I'm new to stackoverflow and it is embarrassing to use the new type of text editor.

Comment: @Minjae _"Oh is that the reason why I got instant -3?"_ Amongst other reasons, yes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the advise, but I'm new to stackoverflow text editor and it is really hard to use for beginners, like me. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user1274820 they have [identical output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c463a8d66565c54d)

Comment: If the code you have is indented, just copy-paste it as-is into the body of the question, mark the code snippet and then use the "Code sample" toolbar button (which looks like `{}`) and it should in most cases work fine

Comment: 'a' is type of `char`, which is single character. "a" is type of `char *`, which is pointer to character array. you can write something like "abc" but not 'abc'.

Comment: @user1274820 I triple checked, but to me it seems exactly the same.

Comment: I guess my question was unclear. 
My question 1: difference between  i++ and ++i in for-loop
question 2: difference between ' ' and " "

Comment: @Minjae did you get it or do you need more explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of a for loop is

`for(int i=0; i<10; i++)`

`int i=0;` is the initializer. This is run only once at the before the for loop even starts.

`i<10` this is the condition it is evaluated *before* every loop.

`i++` is the afterthought. It is run *after* every loop.

So in your example even though yes, `++row` and `++col` increment the variable. It doesn't happen until *after* the body of the loop.

Therefore using `++row` or `row++` makes no difference to the end result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still unclear with the use of increment. When I use increment in for-loop, do ++i and i++ make no difference?.

Comment: It makes no difference in this context @Minjae

Comment: @FirstStep Thank you!